# API to get access_token and login in anypoint with user custom domain and saml azure authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, mule, mulesoft, mule4

Requirement is to login and get the access_token of anypoint plateform to perform some operation on design center or exchange rest api.

If MFA is enabled then by using the connected app we can get the token but facing difficulties in case we are using user custom domain for login with azure authentication.

Please let me the process to create REST api to get the access_token in case we are using user custom domain for login with azure authentication.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by a custom domain for authentication?

Comment: Are you using is single sign-on with an external identity provider (https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/external-identity)? And what is the problem that you have with connected apps in that scenario?

Comment: @aled custom domain means when we login to https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/login/ here you can see use customer domain and and there we have to provide organization domain name. I think i need to implement saml based authentication. That api implementation i need.

Comment: Can you elaborate the "facing difficulties" part? Are you seeing any error? how are you trying to get access token? What does this have to do with `azure-active-directory`?

Comment: In addition to the question from @HarshankBansal please clarify what is the problem with the Connected App method.

Comment: @aled it's not connected app. It's SAML based authentication.

Comment: My question is, what is preventing you of using a connected app anyway?

Comment: @aled It's saml based authentication so we are not using username and password of anypoint plateform. connected app requires user,password,client_id and client_secret. So my question is how we can get access_token if we are using saml not connected app.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Connected App is the **strongly recommended** way to implement 'service accounts' in Anypoint Platform.

If for some reason you are unable or unwilling to follow the recommended method then you need to get an access token to call Anypoint Platform's REST APIs directly. Because your organization in Anypoint Platform is configured to use [External Identity](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/external-identity) for authentication (aka Single Sign-On) then the details of how to obtain such token should be provided by the administrator of you Identity Provider. Usually they can implement several authentication methods, like OAuth 2.0, SAML or others. However the administrators may choose to restrict which methods are allowed, and what requirements they have. For example they may require some Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) mechanism. You need to contact your administrators team for details.

Assuming that by 'azure authentication` you mean that your organization is using Azure AD as the Identity Provider (IdP), then you can look at its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/console-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-dotnet-core) on how to get an access token to understand better what steps may be needed to implement an application that performs those steps.